# Diffusive Limits for compound poisson process

Tags: jump-diffusion, poisson-process

I was reading about compounded Hawkes process and came across diffusive limit theorems.
Where can I find diffusive limit theorems for Poisson processes.

I am new to this area, is there a nice introductory book where I can read about compound processes and their limits?